# Symony2: How to Generate Entity Classes with a subclass (as in symfony 1)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony1, doctrine

In symfony2 the doctrine generator creates a class for each entity. So the approach to add new behavior to these entities (please correct me if I'm wrong) is to add the new custom methods directly in those generated classes.

I'd rather like the approach of symfony 1 where an empty subclass was created and custom methods were placed there. But I'm struggling to use this approach in Symfony2.

Is there a way to generate (and then be able to update) this "Base Entity & SubClass" structure?

If not, why is it better to have all generated and custom code all together?

**Edit**

I've been playing a bit with the entity generator, both generate:doctrine:entity and doctrine:generate:entities (which are different commands), and analyzing the your answers. It seems that another disadvantage of having all in the same file is the update/regeneration of the entities (for example when a new field is added, and the getters and setters need to be regenerated). With these commands you can set the 'regenerateEntityIfExists' but that overrides the old file, deleting you custom code.

I'm thinking to extend the Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand\GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand to build the old structure (base class with generated code and empty subclass for custom code) which allowed having the custom code separated from the generated one, be able to update the entities to add/remove fields, etc.

**But I still wonder why did the development team decided to change the approach used in Symfony1 to this new one. Which are the advantages?**

Thanks!

Comment: I face the same problem as you have. Did you already find a solution to this problem? I'm thinking of using mapped supperclasses. But no idea if this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the logic only involves a single Entity, put it into the Entity class directly.   If the logic involves multiple entities, create a new class in a separate namespace and make it a service.  Inject the entities you want to perform logic on into this service object and perform the logic there.

This helps you keep a separation of concerns in your entity classes and promotes reuse and testability of your service objects.

For example, if you have a Product entity for products and a Tax entity for tax rates for those products, you might make a ProductTaxManager object and inject the Product and Tax entities into this object to do the calculations.

I'm not sure if the service container was much a part of the original Symfony. but you should definitely do some reading at http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/service_container.html

By the way, a repository class should only be used for database queries that involve the Entity by itself only, example being FindAllSortedByAddedDate and such.

Comment: Nice, this is what I was looking for, and is the kind of architecure I was using in Symfony1. Still I feed uncomfortable putting my custom code next to the generated one and wonder why the change it in this new version. Which benefits does it bring to have all together in a long never-ending file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about Entities and Repositories. I didnt get into symfony until 2.0 so im not as familiar with 1.X workings. But you can have a Base Entity then your Repository is where you would load all of your custom functions.

check out http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes for more info on custom repository classes

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom EntityRepository for each entity.
In that class you can add custom behavior of that entity.
Please [see the symfony2 documents](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

Comment: Nisam, @Chausser thanks for your answers. I'm aware of repositories, but it is not what I'm looking for. As I understand (and said in the docs) repositories is where to put custom "Query" logic (things closer to the DB). What I'm looking for is the correct/best practice place where to put custom logic related to the entities themselves (business logic). Ej: In a Product it might be a calculatePriceWithTaxes method, or in a Client a getAllowedHours (calculated based on other fields and business rules). Thanks again and sorry if the original question was not clear enough.

Comment: @user2453714, when you define entity repository like this Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductRepository
it will generate an empty repository class inherited from your entity class (i think the subclass like sf1).You can write your own logic in that repository class.Note:the repositor class  will automatically generate when we are using sf2 commands (ie $ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme)

Comment: then I'm definety doing something wrong, as the RepositoryClass that I got generated is extending EntityRepository and not the entity.